# Is there an alternative to gitlab-runner?

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

I would like to know if there is an alternative to gitlab runners compatible with bitbucket.

The main functionnalities i'm searching for is to install an executor on my server and use it to run some commands on the server where it is installed.

I've tried circle-ci, bitbucket pipelines and travis but all of those require to be connect to my server over ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like the gitlab ci you can use it as a CI for bitbucket.

Just [mirror your bitbucket repo](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/repository_mirroring.html) on gitlab and your will be able to use all of gitlab ci features.

"The following are some possible use cases for repository mirroring:

You migrated to GitLab but still need to keep your project in another source. In that case, you can simply set it up to mirror to GitLab (pull) and all the essential history of commits, tags, and branches will be available in your GitLab instance."

It works on gitlab.com and also on gitlab self hosted (CE or Enterprise)